# Angular Cli : Adding a button Spinner while loading the content

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I want to show a loading spinner or some text with "please wait" as long as it's done in **Angular Cli** .

For example : **Get Quotes**

---

This is **quotes.component.html :**

```
<div class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onGetQuotes()">Get Quotes</div>
<hr>
<app-quote *ngFor="let quote of quotes" [quote]="quote" (quoteDelete)="onDelete($event)"></app-quote>
```

And this is **quotes.component.ts :**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Response } from '@angular/http';
import {Quote} from "../quote.interface";
import {QuoteService} from "../quote.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-quotes',
  templateUrl: './quotes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./quotes.component.css']
})
export class QuotesComponent implements OnInit {
  quotes : Quote[];
  constructor(private quoteService:QuoteService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }


  onGetQuotes(){
    this.quoteService.getQuotes()
    .subscribe(
        (quotes:Quote[]) => this.quotes = quotes,
        (error:Response) =>console.log(error)
    );
  }



}
```

And **quote.service.ts :**

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {Http , Response,Headers} from "@angular/http";
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import {Observable} from "rxjs";
import {AuthService} from "./auth.service";
@Injectable()
export class QuoteService {
    constructor(private http:Http, private authService:AuthService) {

    }


    getQuotes():Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get('http://localhost:8000/api/quotes')
            .map(
                (response:Response)=> {
                    return response.json().quotes;
                }
            );
    }

}
```

So , i want to show a loading page as long as it's done .
Thanks For Reading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a boolean flag to `true` while you are waiting for your service to fetch the data.

`<div *ngIf="fetchingQuotes">please wait</div>`

And in your component.ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-quotes',
  templateUrl: './quotes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./quotes.component.css']
})
export class QuotesComponent implements OnInit {
  quotes : Quote[];
  fetchingQuotes = false;
  constructor(private quoteService:QuoteService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }


  onGetQuotes(){
    this.fetchingQuotes = true;
    this.quoteService.getQuotes()
    .subscribe(
        (quotes:Quote[]) => this.quotes = quotes,
        (error:Response) =>console.log(error)
        this.fetchingQuotes = false
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: remove ";" end of "this.fetchingQuotes = false;"   and thanks !

Answer (score 0):

In your main html file where you keep  you need to keep the html of spinner so you can show it in any component throughout your angular app :

You also need to import service in the app.component.ts:

app.component.ts:

```
constructor(
public serviceName: ServiceName
...
)
```

app.component.html:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<div *ngIf="serviceName.showSpinner" class="spiner">
   <!-- svg or gif of spinner  -->
</div>
```

In your service.ts:

```
public showSpinner: boolean = false;

getdata() {
 // show spinner when we start making request

   this.showLoadingSpinner();
   let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
   let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
   let url = servUrl+apiname; 
   return this.http.post(url, clientJson,clientJson1)
   .map((res: Response) => {
       // response received so hide spinner now
       this.hideLoadingSpinner();
      return res.json();
   });
}

showLoadingSpinner() {
  this.showSpinner = true;
}

hideLoadingSpinner() {
  this.showSpinner = false;
}
```